# Testfor command problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help specifying a testfor command!

As of right now the command is `/testfor @e[type=Item,r=4] {Item:{id:minecraft:anvil}}`

How can I test this anvil for a damage, enchant, or name tag?

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you using?

Comment: There's 3 variations of anvil; Anvil, Damaged_anvil, very_damaged_anvil use these tags

Comment: No it does not seem to work can u plz rewrite the command but with the tag included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To testfor the Item's damage, use the "Damage" tag.

```
/testfor @e[type=Item,r=4] {Item:{id:"minecraft:anvil",Damage:0s}}
```

To test for a custom name, you can use the "tag" tag. With this tag you can define NBT tags for non-entity items. (Items in a player's inventory)
In this case, you need the "display" tag

```
/testfor @e[type=Item,r=4] {Item:{id:"minecraft:anvil",Damage:0s,tag:{display:{Name:"Custom Name Here"}}}}
```